# NSJSONSerialization parsing data issue

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps-api-3, time, nsjsonserialization

I am parsing below data:-

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=40.714353,-74.005973&destination=40.650000,-73.950000&sensor=false&units=metric&mode=transit&departure_time=1396594530&alternatives=true"];
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:URL];
NSDictionary *dataDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
```

Only part of Result not full result showing:

```
2014-04-04 15:24:10.036 Animation[478:907] {

routes =     (
            {
        bounds =             {
            northeast =                 {
                lat = "40.715478";
                lng = "-73.94947789999999";
            };
            southwest =                 {
                lat = "40.6497484";
                lng = "-74.01035299999999";
            };
        };
        copyrights = "Map data \U00a92014 Google";
        legs =             (
                            {
                "arrival_time" =                     {
                    text = "03:35"; <<----- missing "am"
                    "time_zone" = "America/New_York";
                    value = 1396596948;
                };
                "departure_time" =                     {
                    text = "03:02";<<----- missing "am"
                    "time_zone" = "America/New_York";
                    value = 1396594936;
                };`
```

when use this on simulator Correct result is coming, again showing part of response :-

```
    {
   "routes" : [
      {
         "bounds" : {
            "northeast" : {
               "lat" : 40.715478,
               "lng" : -73.94947789999999
            },
            "southwest" : {
               "lat" : 40.6497484,
               "lng" : -74.01035299999999
            }
         },
         "copyrights" : "Map data ©2014 Google",
         "legs" : [
            {
               "arrival_time" : {
                  "text" : "3:35am", <<----- showing "am"
                  "time_zone" : "America/New_York",
                  "value" : 1396596948
               },
               "departure_time" : {
                  "text" : "3:02am",<<----- showing "am"
                  "time_zone" : "America/New_York",
                  "value" : 1396594936
               }
```

And same code is working on simulator fine.

Comment: i think try sensor=True. i think this is problem .

Comment: same issue,I did tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass the `language` when calling the maps api. Setting the language to en_US leads to the desired result:

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=40.714353,-74.005973&destination=40.650000,-73.950000&sensor=false&units=metric&mode=transit&departure_time=1396594530&alternatives=true&language=en_US"];
```

Comment: how did you get to know that?

Comment: Google provides [a nice documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Language)